# submission error in ovtave 4.0.0

Tags: matlab, octave

this error rised when I tried to submit an assignment :
*Submission failed: unexpected error: support for url transfers was disabled when Octave was built.*
How can I enable this support for url transfer now?

Comment: Explained here https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Running-Configure-and-Make.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is just a guess since you provided very little information about your system.  Are you the administrator of the system running Octave?  Or are you running on octave-online.net, or a user account on a laboratory computer, or similar?

The version of Octave you're using was likely built with the --without-curl  switch enabled.  I do not believe the functionality is present to just 'turn it back on'.

You would need to recompile Octave with URL transfers enabled. Or reinstall from a binary implementation with URL transfers enabled. Or switch to a different system where you have the system rights to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running octave on Ubuntu and yes I'm admin. In case that I want to recompile how can I make sure that the url transfer is enabled?

Comment: according to the link provided above by Daniel, it should be enabled by default as long as you don't include the `--without-curl` option when running configure.

Comment: if you're on ubuntu, you could also install octave with apt-get